# Predictive simulation of gait on Mars?

Tags: mars, simulation, reference-request, reduced-gravity-sports, moonwalking

In the *Journal of Biomechanics*, Volume 45, Issue 7, 30 April 2012, Pages 1293-1298, [Predictive simulation of gait at low gravity reveals skipping as the preferred locomotion strategy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3327825/) (PDF file of an unedited manuscript that has been accepted for publication), it discusses "skipping as more efficient and less fatiguing than walking or running and suggest the existence of a walk-skip rather than a walk-run transition at low gravity."

**LOCOMOTION SPEED 1.1 m/s** 
[image]
Stick figures of predicted gait patterns using the effort cost function at a locomotion speed of 1.1 m/s. (Bars indicate ground contact of the color-matching foot.)

**LOCOMOTION SPEED 2.0 m/s**

[image]
Stick figures of predicted gait patterns using the fatigue cost function at a locomotion speed of 2.0 m/s. (Bars indicate ground contact of the color-matching foot.)

Has there been any other predictive simulation studies of gait, especially relating to Mars gravity?

Comment: Very cool question and interesting paper! Also, *different* but related questions: [What would the human gait look like on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32865/12102) and [At what surface gravity can't astronauts do full steps anymore?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35809/12102)

Comment: Might want to look into ARGOS studies